# Fix width in Outlook Email 2010,2016,2019

Tags: html, css, outlook, html-email

Any suggestions as to what I can do to adjust my styles so that it looks better in Outlook 2010, 2016, and 2019?  2010 it just is pushing further to the left, but 2016 and 2019, it's like there is now second td and so the image and the button are breaking up the text.

```
    #content_container{
        width:100%;
    }
    .orange_hdr{
        color:#F04C23;
        font-size:20px;
        font-weight:700;
        font-family:sans-serif,Helvetica,Arial;
    }
    .orange_hdr td{
        padding-left:35px;
    }
    .content{
        font-family:sans-serif,Helvetica,Arial;
        font-size:14px;
        padding-left:35px;
    }
       
        <table id="content_container">
          <tr class="orange_hdr">
            <td width="400">Want to respond to <br> customers more quickly?<br>
              <br>
            </td>
            <td width="200" rowspan="2">
              <img  src="https://mcusercontent.com/986b6bf5d11ba71840c119f4e/images/4304fc23-dd6e-4bed-9726-a8db3a8aaf52.jpg" width="198" alt="">
              <a width="200" href="https://www.selectcomtelecom.ca/business/assets/ebooks/UC-One_eBook_English_final.pdf"><img style="float: right;" src="https://mcusercontent.com/986b6bf5d11ba71840c119f4e/images/e71349b7-a2e9-46cd-9a83-9e8481a5fa9a.jpg" width="198" alt=""></a>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="content" width="400">
              Dear [name],<br>
              <br>
              Being ready means giving your staff smarter tools <br>
              so that they can communicate effectively across <br>
              multiple devices, technologies and locations.<br>
              <br>
              Top executives now spend nearly one day a week <br>
              managing communications. Getting on top of a <br>
              constantly shifting landscape will benefit you and <br>
              your staff.  <br>
              <br>
              <br><strong>Our new solution makes sense on every level</strong>
              <br>
              <br>
              Cisco UC-One makes getting in touch simple again <br>
              by bringing your landline, mobile, laptop and tablets <br>
              into a single cloud-based system – helping you <br>
              become a Ready business, one that’s poised to <br>
              take advantage of change.<br>
              <br>
              The solution is designed to make it easier for your <br>
              people to work together and helps you reduce and <br>
              control costs by giving you a predictable monthly <br>
              fee per user. And because you get a dedicated <br>
              service team, the system is easy to manage.<br>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: Can you provide screenshots demonstrating the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your first `tr` has two `td's` and second has one. I have fixed the code below for you. You can just use the html block for your tests.

```css
    #content_container{
        width:100%;
    }
    .orange_hdr{
        color:#F04C23;
        font-size:20px;
        font-weight:700;
        font-family:sans-serif,Helvetica,Arial;
    }
    .orange_hdr td{
        padding-left:35px;
    }
    .content{
        font-family:sans-serif,Helvetica,Arial;
        font-size:14px;
        padding-left:35px;
    }
```

```html
       
        <table id="content_container">
          <tr class="orange_hdr">
            <td>
                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="400">Want to respond to <br> customers more quickly?<br>
              <br></td>
                            <td width="200"><img  src="https://mcusercontent.com/986b6bf5d11ba71840c119f4e/images/4304fc23-dd6e-4bed-9726-a8db3a8aaf52.jpg" width="198" alt="">
              <a width="200" href="https://www.selectcomtelecom.ca/business/assets/ebooks/UC-One_eBook_English_final.pdf"><img style="float: right;" src="https://mcusercontent.com/986b6bf5d11ba71840c119f4e/images/e71349b7-a2e9-46cd-9a83-9e8481a5fa9a.jpg" width="198" alt=""></a></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="content" width="400">
              Dear [name],<br>
              <br>
              Being ready means giving your staff smarter tools <br>
              so that they can communicate effectively across <br>
              multiple devices, technologies and locations.<br>
              <br>
              Top executives now spend nearly one day a week <br>
              managing communications. Getting on top of a <br>
              constantly shifting landscape will benefit you and <br>
              your staff.  <br>
              <br>
              <br><strong>Our new solution makes sense on every level</strong>
              <br>
              <br>
              Cisco UC-One makes getting in touch simple again <br>
              by bringing your landline, mobile, laptop and tablets <br>
              into a single cloud-based system – helping you <br>
              become a Ready business, one that’s poised to <br>
              take advantage of change.<br>
              <br>
              The solution is designed to make it easier for your <br>
              people to work together and helps you reduce and <br>
              control costs by giving you a predictable monthly <br>
              fee per user. And because you get a dedicated <br>
              service team, the system is easy to manage.<br>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
```